# ASP.NET MVC and URL Rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

In my Controller, I have 4 ActionResult (Show, Search, Modify and Delete) for the View. For the 3 last, there are a RedirectToAction() as Actionesult and in Route I have a custom as this :

```
routes.RouteMap("Detail", "/Show/{id}", new { controller : "Administration", action : "Show", id : UrlParameters.Optional });
```

I need to add 2 parameters in url when I get the result of Search. This 2 parameters are sent in POST. 
How to add this parameters in url rewritting as is ?

When I come on the View

```
http://localhost/Show/1
```

After a Search

```
http://localhost/Show/1/foo/foo
```

Thanks for helping :)

[EDIT] After some test, I found the solution.
Forms and Controller are in POST unless the Show (GET | POST).

There is 2 routes :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "RechercheEtablissementGucps",
                "DetailGucps/{idGucps}/{CategorieEtablissementValue}/{SearchField}",
                new { controller = "Administration", action = "AfficheDetailGuCPS", idGucps = UrlParameter.Optional, CategorieEtablissementValue = UrlParameter.Optional, SearchField = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

routes.MapRoute(
                "Gucps", // Route name
                "DetailGucps/{idGucps}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Administration", action = "AfficheDetailGuCPS", idGucps = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I have then the parameters as desired if I search and nothing if another Action is done

```
/DetailGucps/29/DIR/fr
```

Comment: You cannot put a POST in a URL.

Comment: Hmm yes, but I can't add this in the Controller or by the Route ?

Comment: as @Slaks said you cannot put a POST in a URL. And because with routes you are defining how your urls will look like, well, you can't.

Comment: If i update all methods in GET, I have 404 Error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
routes.RouteMap("Detail", "/Show/{id}/{p1}/{p2}", new { controller : "Administration", action : "Show", id : UrlParameters.Optional, p1: UrlParameters.Optional, p2: UrlParameters.Optional });
```

and add the new params to the target actions signature.

Comment: I have add a Route as above and it works :), but when I have any parameters, the url contains this "System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter,System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter". How to remove the parameters from url when it's null ?

Comment: are the params on the action nullable?

Comment: can i see your action signature?

Comment: Here the signature of Show Action : `public ActionResult AfficheDetailGuCPS(Int64 idGucps, EquipeGUCps equipeGUCps, string categorieEtablissementValue, string searchField)` String can be null, no ?

Answer (score 1):

in essence what you are doing seems incorrect to me.

It seems like you are trying to pass **query parameters** as **route values**.

Also there is an issue with using more than one optional parameter for routing, see:

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx

In your action set your parameters you are expecting, ex:

```
public ActionResult Show(int ID, string param1 = null, int? param2 = null)
{
    return View(/*.GetShow(ID, param1, param2)*/);
}

[HttpMethod.Post]
public ActionResult Show(FormCollection collection)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Show", new { ID = collection["ID"], param1 = collection["param1"], param2 = collection["param2"] });
}
```

If you get the idea :)

Comment: Thank you for example, I'll try to update my code with this. I'm looking for parameters with commas too.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to post the results of search to an Action and then redirect to an Action you would use the [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] attribute and FormCollection instead of naming Post parameters in your routing definition. So you should only define the Show route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Show", // Route name
            "Administration/Show/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Administration", action = "Show", 
                       id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

The HttpVerb attributes will ensure that your post is routed correctly when posting:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Show(int? id)
    {
        var showViewModel = new ShowViewModel();

        // ... populate ViewModel

        return View(showViewModel);
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Modify(FormCollection form)
    {
        var id = form["id"];
        var p1 = form["p1"];
        var p2 = form["p2"];

        // ... Modify

        return RedirectToAction("Show", new { id = id });
    }
```

Comment: Not really my wish ;) I need to RedirectToAction and append the result of the search in the url. I try this example, but no where a parameter is added.

Comment: @User.Anonymous - in your question you say you wish to achieve this with a POST but this is not possible

Comment: I try with all my 4 methods in GET (in form and in Controller), but now I have 404 Error...